# Updating auto layout constraints to reposition Text Field

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I am currently working my way through the `Udacity` iOS Development Nanaodegree and have come up against a problem that I am really struggling to solve. I am new to development, and Stackoverflow, so this is my first post.... here it goes;

I am building an app used to generate Memes. It does that by allowing a user to pick an image and enter some text.

I have a `UIView`. In that `UIView` I have 2x `UIToolbar`, 2x `UITextField` and a `UIImageView`. The toolbars are positioned at the top and bottom of the view, the text fields beneath and above them respectively. The `UIImageView` space the full with and height of the view, and is underneath the toolbars and textInputs.

See here for [screenshots of Storyboard and app](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-VyqP0WP7X9YTNGQWNVLWg3VWc/view?usp=sharing)

The user is able to select an image from their Album, or take a photo with their camera, to populate the `UIImageView`. The `UIImageView` is then set to `Aspect Fit` to keep its correct aspect ratio.

I have setup constraints in Interface Builder so that the `UITextFields` are positioned at a constant distance to the top and bottom toolbars.

The problem I have is that the user needs to rotate the device to position the text fields so that they are positioned on the top and bottom of the image. What I mean by this is that if the user selects a landscape image, and the device is in portrait, the user would need to rotate their device to ensure that the text fields are positioned on top of the image.

What I would like to do is reposition the textFields after the user has selected or taken an image and the image has had Aspect Fit applied.

It has been suggested that I could use `AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInside` to produce a `CGRect` with the same dimensions of the `UIImage` after it has has Aspect Fit applied, use the CGRect to update the frame of the `UIImageView`, and then update the constraints.

I have managed to produce the new `CGRect` and update the frame of the `UIImageView`. I have then changed my constraints on the `UITextFields` so that they align with the `UIImageView` instead of the toolbar however the `UITextFields` don't reposition themselves when the frame is updated.

I call the following after the frame has been updated;

```
view.setNeedUpdateConstraints()
```

If anyone has an idea at the best way to approach this problem that would be great.

**EDIT:**

Here is the code from the viewController in project I have created to isolate and try to solve this issue..

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewPic: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topTextToToolberContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomTextToToolbarConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var topText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomText: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let imageToDisplay = UIImage(named: "Captain-Picard-Facepalm")
        imageViewPic.image = imageToDisplay
    }

    func updateFrame() {        
        let resizedImageSize = imageViewPic.image!.size
        let imageViewBounds = imageViewPic.bounds
        let newRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(resizedImageSize, imageViewBounds)
        imageViewPic.frame = newRect
    }

    override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
        updateFrame()
        view.setNeedsLayout()
    }
}
```

Comment: Put `[self setNeedsLayout];` very after the line which update the frame.

Comment: @Kampai alas this did not solve the issue :(

Comment: Do one thing add frame changing code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an example of someone doing a very similar. This is the approach.

1. In the storyboard, only apply 3 constraints to each of the UITextFields, leaving the top constraints of the topTextField, and the bottom constraint of the bottomTextField.
2. Add two properties to the ViewController for the top and bottom constraints.

   ```
   var topConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!
   var bottomConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!
   ```
3. Create the following helper method;

   ```
   func layoutTextFields() {

   //Remove any existing constraints
   if topConstraint != nil {
       view.removeConstraint(topConstraint)
   }

   if bottomConstraint != nil {
       view.removeConstraint(bottomConstraint)
   }

   //Get the position of the image inside the imageView
   let size = memeImageView.image != nil ? memeImageView.image!.size : memeImageView.frame.size
   let frame = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(size, memeImageView.bounds)

   //A margin for the new constrains; 10% of the frame's height
   let margin = frame.origin.y + frame.size.height * 0.10

   //Create and add the new constraints
   topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
       item: topTextField,
       attribute: .Top,
       relatedBy: .Equal,
       toItem: memeImageView,
       attribute: .Top,
       multiplier: 1.0,
       constant: margin)
   view.addConstraint(topConstraint)

   bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
       item: bottomTextField,
       attribute: .Bottom,
       relatedBy: .Equal,
       toItem: memeImageView,
       attribute: .Bottom,
       multiplier: 1.0,
       constant: -margin)
   view.addConstraint(bottomConstraint) 
   }
   ```
4. Call the helper method in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`function

   ```
   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
   super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
   layoutTextFields()
   }
   ```

This seems to work perfectly both when the UIImageView doesn't have an image and also when it doesn't. It also works when you rotate the device.

There two areas I was getting caught up on was thinking I needed to have all the  constraints defined in Storyboard first, as well as thinking I needed to add a view into the hierarchy using the `CGRect` produced by `AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect`

Answer (score 0):

I observe that the problem here is of drawing/rendering views. So things like views are drawing before actual layout happens, it means frame will not change until views are not render.

What you can do here is force layout early before actual drawing happens. There is a method available, which can takes care of force layout views when view's frame update.

```
func setNeedsLayout()
func layoutIfNeeded()
```

Above both methods are used to force layout of views.

Try below code which can takes care of updating layout.

```
func updateFrame() {        
    let resizedImageSize = imageViewPic.image!.size
    let imageViewBounds = imageViewPic.bounds
    let newRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(resizedImageSize, imageViewBounds)
    imageViewPic.frame = newRect
    imageViewPic.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Also override below method in ViewController. `updateViewConstraints()` method used to update custom constraints.

```
override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.imageViewPic.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```